# Rails Authority Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

We're using authority for our application.
[link](https://github.com/nathanl/authority)

How can I check the installation? I've followed the steps in the doc, but it seems that the ApplicationAuthority class is not being called. I tried adding an error in the class and the application didn't fail.

Also, there's no exceptions for this part in the model.

```
include Authority::Abilities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else having this problem - you need to add authorization to your controllers as well.  [Here](https://github.com/nathanl/authority#controllers) is the relevant part of the documentation - essentially, just add `authorize_actions_for Model` to the top as if it were a `before_filter`.